# Google Map API v3 'click' event only working if double clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

Once again, I have a strange minor issue with Google Map API v3.  I'm sure I've over-looked something easy, but after looking for an answer for hours, I'm ready to ask for help.

I have a polygon shape that I finally figured out how to zoom into on a click... except that now instead of it zooming into the polygon on a single click, it takes a double-click.  What is baffling me is that the script is for a single click.  Here is the portion of the script I'm referring to:

```
    // Add a listener for the click event
  google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'center_changed', function() {     
      window.setTimeout(function() {
          map.panTo(marker.position());
      }, 1000);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function() {
      map.setCenter(marker.position(29.737, -95.394),
      map.setZoom(18)
      );
  });
```

Here is a link to a working page:  http://www.conleym.com/map/google_maps_code_9_zoom.html
*The only polygon currently set up to zoom is polygon1 - the blue shape at the top of the map.

I've tested it on Firefox(23), IE(9) and Chrome(16) all with same results.

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at my question regarding Google Maps here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689705/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box

Comment: What is "zone1"? If it is a polygon it does not have a center_changed event....and where did "marker" come from? Also there is no method marker.position().

Comment: Zone 1 is the polygon being referred to.  I'm just learning javascript and since this code isn't working properly, I'm sure it isn't entirely correct, but it's semi-working, which is why I'm confused and have posted here to see if someone could help.  I was referred to the code shown a user on another site:  (http://pastebin.com/TLEJhDci)  Apologies for the .position, which is .getPosition in the original code - I have been trying anything and everything to figure this out and posted my most recent try.  If anyone can give me some guidance I would really appreciate it.

Comment: also wanted to mention, adding to my confusion - when I put .getPosition back in instead of just .position (which I know is bad), the single click works, but it zooms on the center of the original map instead of the polygon shape being clicked (zone1 in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want the map to zoom to the "bounds" of the polygon (to show the whole polygon).  In that case you can do something like this (for each zone); and remove the "center_changed" listeners on the polygons:

```
zone1._myBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i=0; i<triangleCoords.length; i++)
{
   zone1._myBounds.extend(triangleCoords[i]);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(zone1, 'click', function () {
  map.fitBounds(zone1._myBounds);
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/conleym_com_google_maps_code_9_zoom.html)

Note that this approach is not very extensible (I would suggest making a function that takes the data for the polygon, does all this, then pushes the references onto an array for later use).

Comment: Thanks a million - this helps me out tremendously!