# R Shiny map search input box

Tags: r, autocomplete, shiny, r-leaflet, googleway

In google maps, the search input box auto completes addresses as a user types.  Is there a way to do this in R Shiny with access to the autocomplete value in order to use with a mapping package?

[image]

There is a javascript method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689705/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box).  I've tried to use this method in R Shiny in the code below. SymbolixAU pointed out using `google_map( search_box = TRUE )` which is a simple solution.  Unfortunately it doesn't work in my code and also because I would like the search box to be separate from the map.

The attempt below has a text input `my_address`, text output `copy_of_address` and a googleway map `my_map` in this order on the page.

The intended behaviour is for a user to enter text into text input `my_address`, have it autocomplete with an address (this works), the address will be copied into text output `copy_of_address` (this only shows what was typed, not the autocompleted version) and finally the map is to be centred on this address.

[image: The shiny app]

See that the input box has the autocomplete address, however the copy of the address and map is using only the user input text.

In the code below, replace `MyKey` with your google api key (sometimes an empty string works).

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

key <- "MyKey"
set_key(key = key)
google_keys()

ui <- shiny::basicPage(

  div(
    textInput(inputId = "my_address", label = "")    
    ,textOutput(outputId = "copy_of_address")
    ,HTML(paste0("
          <script>
            function initAutocomplete() {
            new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('my_address')),
            {types: ['geocode']}
            );
            }
            </script>
            <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=", key,"&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'
            async defer></script>
    "))
    ,google_mapOutput(outputId = "my_map")
  )

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  my_address <- reactive({
    input$my_address
  })

  output$copy_of_address <- renderText({
    my_address()
  })

  output$my_map <- renderGoogle_map({
    my_address <- my_address()
    validate(
      need(my_address, "Address not available")
    )

    df <- google_geocode(address = my_address)
    my_coords <- geocode_coordinates(df)
    my_coords <- c(my_coords$lat[1], my_coords$lng[1])

    google_map(
      location = my_coords,
      zoom = 12,
      map_type_control = FALSE,
      zoom_control = FALSE,
      street_view_control = FALSE
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Are you using this on a map, or independent of a map (i.e, a separate widget)?

Comment: At the moment I have a map below the text box being used for the address - so it is not independent of a map.  The map will centre on the address after it is entered.

Comment: If you use `google_map( search_box = TRUE )` it will place a search box on the map and autocomplete

Comment: [here's an example of a shiny](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/blob/master/tests/manual_tests.R#L418), using the search box, and observing the results of what the user searches for.

Comment: Is there a way to have the search box outside the map but still work together?  The use case is entering the address first and then showing the map.

Comment: There's the `google_place_autocomplete` function, but, I don't think I ever got it to work. Might be worth having a look at. Happy to discuss its implementation over on the github issues page if you don't find an alternative solution.

Comment: @SymbolixAU before you pointed out `search_box` I tried the javascript solution and had the autocomplete working with a text input with `input_id = my_id`.  However when reading the textbox input `input$my_id` the value was only what the user entered, not the autocomplete version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183808/discussion-between-vlad-and-symbolixau).

Answer (score 11):

This wasn't easy for me to figure out, but I think I have a *reasonable* solution.   It ultimately came down to copying and pasting the example from Google *very* carefully, reading about sending messages from Javascript to Shiny, putting the ideas together, and getting lucky on the 200th attempt...

To Give Credit Where It's Due:

Google's link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

RStudio's Link: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-send-message.html

My *potential* solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(googleway)

key <- "MyKey"
set_key(key = key)
#google_keys()

ui <- shiny::basicPage(

  div(
    textInput(inputId = "my_address", label = "Type An Address")    
    ,textOutput(outputId = "full_address")
    ,HTML(paste0(" <script> 
                function initAutocomplete() {

                 var autocomplete =   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('my_address'),{types: ['geocode']});
                 autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address',  'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
                 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                 if (!place.geometry) {
                 return;
                 }

                 var addressPretty = place.formatted_address;
                 var address = '';
                 if (place.address_components) {
                 address = [
                 (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[4] && place.address_components[4].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[5] && place.address_components[5].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[7] && place.address_components[7].short_name || '')
                 ].join(' ');
                 }
                 var address_number =''
                 address_number = [(place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '')]
                 var coords = place.geometry.location;
                 //console.log(address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValue', address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueAddressNumber', address_number);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValuePretty', addressPretty);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueCoords', coords);});}
                 </script> 
                 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=", key,"&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete' async defer></script>"))
    ,google_mapOutput(outputId = "my_map")
    )

    )

server <- function(input, output) {

  my_address <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$jsValueAddressNumber)){
      if(length(grep(pattern = input$jsValueAddressNumber, x = input$jsValuePretty ))==0){
        final_address<- c(input$jsValueAddressNumber, input$jsValuePretty)
      } else{
        final_address<- input$jsValuePretty
      }
      final_address
    }
  })


  output$full_address <- renderText({
    if(!is.null(my_address())){
      my_address()
    }
  })

  output$my_map <- renderGoogle_map({
    my_address <- my_address()
    shiny::validate(
      need(my_address, "Address not available")
    )

    not_a_df <- google_geocode(address = my_address)
    my_coords <- geocode_coordinates(not_a_df)
    my_coords <- c(my_coords$lat[1], my_coords$lng[1])

    google_map(
      location = my_coords,
      zoom = 12,
      map_type_control = FALSE,
      zoom_control = FALSE,
      street_view_control = FALSE
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope this helps. Cheers!
--nate

Comment: Does this also answer your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848254/shinydashboard-google-places-autocomplete-invalidvalueerror-not-an-instance-o) ?

Comment: No. This was my answer to @Vlad. I thought it was a great idea and wanted to put it into a `shinydashboard` I built. However, I encountered the `InvalidValueError` problem when I switched from a `shiny` app to a `shinydashboard`.

Comment: oh I see. yeah it's strange you get the error in the dashboard then.

Comment: I have a partial solution. I'll add it to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54848254/shinydashboard-google-places-autocomplete-invalidvalueerror-not-an-instance-o

Comment: Hi! Maybe someone still read this: Does this solution still work today? I tried to mimic it and my input window always gets grayed out after a few seconds and get the display "Opps! Something went wrong." in the textbox. I'm grateful for any hints! @nate