# Mapping two reactive datasets with Leaflet & Googleway in R

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, googleway

I'm trying to utilize Google's API for their drop down search feature to map a selected address using Leaflet. However, I also have an existing dataset that I'd like to add to the Leaflet map based on a checkboxInput. This means that both need to be reactive, and I'm having a hard time rbind-ing this data.

I have utilized code from the responses to [R Shiny map search input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347495/r-shiny-map-search-input-box) in order to create the code in the ui function that creates the Google dropdown.

I am using RCurl to pull in a dataset from Google Drive

```
library(RCurl)
library(shiny)
library(googleway)
myCsv <- getURL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTc6H0ikgU53DJsGWzaSJO__77xIVkwAbyI2vjkYuHSAjj9hzWVtVAOhah8B5baDO4ilfqJTm5OWFzW/pub?output=csv")
location_data = read.csv(textConnection(myCsv))
```

or if easier to read in via table:

```
Locations Latitude Longitude
location1 40.72993 -74.00022
location2 40.72993 -74.00022
location3 40.67678 -73.98048
location4 40.76954 -73.95436
location5 40.72504 -73.98145
location6 40.80251 -73.96745
```

My ui function:

```
ui <- basicPage(
  div(
    checkboxInput("checkbox", "Map Other Locations", value = FALSE),
    textInput(inputId = "my_address", label = "Type An Address")    
    ,textOutput(outputId = "full_address")

    #Google HTML dropdown code
    ,HTML(paste0(" <script> 
                function initAutocomplete() {

                 var autocomplete =   new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('my_address'),{types: ['geocode']});
                 autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address',  'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);
                 autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
                 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                 if (!place.geometry) {
                 return;
                 }

                 var addressPretty = place.formatted_address;
                 var address = '';
                 if (place.address_components) {
                 address = [
                 (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[3] && place.address_components[3].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[4] && place.address_components[4].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[5] && place.address_components[5].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[6] && place.address_components[6].short_name || ''),
                 (place.address_components[7] && place.address_components[7].short_name || '')
                 ].join(' ');
                 }
                 var address_number =''
                 address_number = [(place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || '')]
                 var coords = place.geometry.location;
                 //console.log(address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValue', address);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueAddressNumber', address_number);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValuePretty', addressPretty);
                 Shiny.onInputChange('jsValueCoords', coords);});}
                 </script> 
                 <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=", key,"&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete' async defer></script>"))

     #map output
     ,leafletOutput("mymap",height = 600)
  )

)
```

My server code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  #if checkbox is checked, rbind location + google data
  #if checkbox not checked, provide google data
  location_data_reactive <- reactive({
    if (input$checkbox == TRUE) { 
        input_address <- input$my_address
        not_a_df <- google_geocode(address = my_address)
        coords <- geocode_coordinates(not_a_df)
        coords_to_rbind <- c(as.character("Input Location"), coords$lat[1], coords$lng[1])
        data_to_map <- rbind(location_data, test_to_rbind)
        final_data <- rbind(location_data, my_coords)
    } else if (input$checkbox == FALSE) { 
        input_address <- input$my_address
        not_a_df <- google_geocode(address = my_address)
        coords <- geocode_coordinates(not_a_df)
        final_data <- c(coords$lat[1], coords$lng[1])
        colnames(final_data) <- c("Latitude", "Longitude")
    } else { location_data[0,] }
  })



  #leaflet map
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    location_data_to_map <- location_data_reactive()

    m <- leaflet(data = location_data_to_map) %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(lng = ~Longitude,
                        lat = ~Latitude
      )
    m
    })

}  

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I receive the below error message for everything I try to do and run with stacking this data or rearranging the if statement.

```
Error: address must be a string of length 1
```

Can anyone assist with stacking these two data reactive data frames? Thank you!

Comment: should `google_geocode(address = my_address)` be `google_geocode(address = input$my_address)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the same problem. Here is what solved it for me :

1. Make sure you have API access to the Google Geocoding API (it is different from the Places API that is used in the upper part of the code) : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start
2. use   `google_geocode(address = my_address())` (notice the extra brackets)