# Autocomplete FORMS usando Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

Does anyone know how I can put an address field with options inside FORMS using Django ?? similar to the one in the image, only that there would be neighborhoods as well. I'm trying to work with Geoip, but if you can give me options or tell me how to do it, I appreciate it.

illustrative picture:
https://scontent.fsdu25-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.6435-9/183553513_4055413947881958_3475192236908351315_n.jpg?_nc_cat=105&ccb=1-3&_nc_sid=825194&_nc_eui2=AeFgw7TrSMCgZIbSrqxk-PjUYUpfRPtoIc5hSl9E-2ghzjE7o86qkRcdtvD4nUt8R-qpnaMPg0aZvKibC_GYvbvV&_nc_ohc=tUx8l-Ik2SUAX-ngCCN&_nc_ht=scontent.fsdu25-1.fna&oh=2f5067c53372bc5503360b8e367dcd06&oe=60C1AB96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RESOLVIDO]

RESPOSTA:
Usei o API JavaScript do Maps / Places Autocomplete

Tem que ter conta de faturamento no google(tem que ativar o faturamento senão não vai rolar com eles, mas o autocomplete é gratuito), dar uma lida no api google maps ajuda. links que me ajudaram: [How to add Google Maps Autocomplete search box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689705/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box)
esse aqui tb: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete?fbclid=IwAR34FvagZzglX3oQUzrBTrWIpIKLFNu09_TmaESHmTnejgnhD_a0ZgIk_BU