# Search box on Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put a search box onto my map, but it keeps failing. I have tried to use sample code from a few sites (here: [How to add Google Maps Autocomplete search box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689705/how-to-add-google-maps-autocomplete-search-box); here: [How to integrate SearchBox in Google Maps JavaScript API v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745469/how-to-integrate-searchbox-in-google-maps-javascript-api-v3); here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox; and a tutorial from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSdM3yZkj1w). But I can't seem to make it work, and now my map won't even display.

To explain fully, I am trying to make a map that displays a kml (which can be toggled), a marker that can be dragged by the user (which displays co-ordinates where ever the marker is), and a search box to search for an address or co-ordinates (...this is still eluding me).

In the end, I am hoping to move the search box and the kml toggle onto the map, rather than outside.

I'm very new to this, so I apologise in advance for my lack of experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Non-working code below:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = null;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var layers=[];
    layers[0] = new  google.maps.KmlLayer("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29079095/Limpopo_Hunting_Zones/Zones_2015.kml",
    {preserveViewport: true});

function toggleLayers(i)
{
    if(layers[i].getMap()==null){
       layers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    else {
       layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.742023, 29.462218);
  var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.460136, 31.3189074);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPosition,
    title: 'Point A',
    map: map,
    draggable: true
  });

  // Update current position info.
  updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
  geocodePosition(latLng);

  // Add dragging event listeners.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
    updateMarkerAddress('DRAGGING...');
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('DRAGGING...');
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    updateMarkerStatus('DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY');
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

}

var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-25.43029134371126, 25.979551931249944),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-21.919517708560267, 32.164854665624944));

var options = {
 bounds: defaultBounds
 };

var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

if (places.length == 0) {
  return;
}
for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}

markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
  var image = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  markers.push(marker);

  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
var bounds = map.getBounds();
searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
});
}

 // Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style>
#mapCanvas {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  float: top;
}
#infoPanel {
  float: top;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#infoPanel div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="SEARCH">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
CLICK TO DISPLAY ZONES <input type="checkbox" id="CLICK TO HUNTING ZONES" onclick="toggleLayers(0);"/>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<div id="infoPanel">
<div id="address"></div>
<b>MARKER STATUS:</b>
<div id="markerStatus"><i>DRAG & DROP THE MARKER ONTO YOUR DESIRED PROPERTY.</i>
</div>
<b>GPS CO-ORDINATES:</b>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: Your map won't display?  Are you getting any JS errors?  This is a curious way to try and loop over an array: `for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++)`  The second part there is typically a while condition, not an assignment like `marker = markers[i]`  Try `for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
  markers[i].setMap(null);`  Similarly with the loop over the places array.

Comment: @duncan - Thanks for your response. It still doesn't seem to work. I got that particular code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox. Perhaps I've put it in the wrong place or something? The map just doesn't show up. The search box and toggle, and GPS co-ordinate info appears...but the map is missing. No errors, that I'm aware of. The map was working perfectly before I started trying to add the search box.